# Passing non-dword arguments onto stack causes page fault?

Tags: assembly, stack, masm, page-fault

I'm currently reading through Irvine 6th ed. to teach myself assembly, and I've come across this sentence on page 277 (section 8.2.2, 'Accessing Stack Parameters', sub-heading 'Passing 8-Bit and 16-Bit Arguments on the Stack'), and it states:

> "Though you can push 16-bit operands onto the stack, doing so prevents ESP from being aligned on a doubleword boundary. A **page fault** may occur and runtime performance may be degraded."

I understand that misaligned memory access can cause performance issues due to the granularity of memory access, but I do not see why a page fault could occur. From my understanding, (hard) page faults occur when an process makes a memory access to a location in virtual memory that is currently not loaded into physical memory.

**1.** Thus, is the quote saying that the stack might exist in several pages at once, and that the misalignment might make a subsequent memory access go over a page boundary?

**2.** In the event that I have answered my own question, would allocating the stack size to be exactly the size of one page (i.e., with `.STACK 4096` directive in MASM) force the stack to exist contiguously on exactly one page, eliminating this problem? Or might the stack still reside across two different pages?

**3.** If the latter is true, wouldn't padding the data (which is suggested) still result in a page fault anyway? E.g: If the 16 byte variable is 'val1', and we want to access a dword following it called 'val2', and stack resides in across two pages, with the page aligned to 0x1000:
       `Before padding                      After padding          
       ----------------                   ----------------         
0x1002 |    [val1]    |            0x1002 | [ PADDING ]  |         
0x1000 | [val2 high]  |            0x1000 |    [val1]    |         
       --PG BOUNDARY---                   ---PG BOUNDARY--         
0x0FFE | [val2 low ]  | PG FAULT!  0x0FFE | [val2 high]  |PG FAULT!
0x0FFC | [irrelevant] |            0x0FFC | [val2 low ]  |         
       ----------------                   ----------------`

Thank you! (and sorry for all the conditional questions, and if I'm over-thinking this)